# Customize Microsoft Word built-in style with numbering

Tags: c#, ms-word, styles, office-interop

I have a word document which already defined costumed built-in style. Like image below.

[image]

I want to change the style of the predefined built-in style by running the C# code below.

```
        // open document
        Object oFilePath = "C://Users/myDoc.docx";   
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document myDoc;
        myDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(ref oFilePath, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing
                       );
        // Change header2 style
        myDoc.Styles[WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2].Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorOrange;


        //save and close doc
        myDoc.Save();
        Object oFalse = false;
        myDoc.Close(ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

The code successfully change the color of heading text, but the number before the text still remains green, not affected by the code. Like the following picture.

[image]

Please give me some hint to also apply the color change to the numbering of heading.Thank you.

Comment: i have no error... at the origin the color is different between number and letter?

Comment: Hi @Frenchy, thanks for reply.  I upload my document here: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GwyoBljXDR1sEBHWP-8SGWE4yfXzAysM) The origin  color of number and letter are the same. But I've found that when creating a new numbering format with color  in number library and its applied by built-in header style. Then the code will not change the number color. However if I manually cancel the current number format and apply other default number format in Word. Then it just worked fine. I wonder is there API to do those thing.

Comment: yes you can do that with the API. test the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that with the API

```
//To Cancel the numerotation
ListTemplate lt = null;
myDoc.Styles[WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2].LinkToListTemplate(lt);

//To add First Level of Numerotation
ListGallery gallery = wrdApp.ListGalleries[WdListGalleryType.wdNumberGallery];
myDoc.Styles[WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2].LinkToListTemplate(gallery.ListTemplates[1]);
```

Comment: Perfect! The solution resolve my problem. Thank you, Frenchy.